# creating a session with shopify API Error : malicious login (Python)

Tags: python, django, session, shopify

I am tring to get the Shop detais as well as i have to put a script tag in to the store .

Folowing all the standerd API calls i have constructed this :

```
scope = ["write_products", "read_orders"]
shopify.Session.setup(api_key='somekey', secret='somekeyagain')
permission_url = shopify.Session.create_permission_url(shop_url, scope)
params = { 'code' : request.REQUEST.get('code'),'timestamp' :request.REQUEST.get('timestamp'),'signature':request.REQUEST.get('signature')}
session = shopify.Session(shop_url, params)
```

All i am getting by this call is this Error :

```
ValidationException at /login/finalize/
Invalid Signature: Possibly malicious login
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/finalize/?code=somecode&shop=myshop.myshopify.com&timestamp=1368003682&signature=somesignature
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: ValidationException
Exception Value:    
Invalid Signature: Possibly malicious login
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you have invalid signature. signature=somesignature . If you take look at source you will see how its checked.  md5(cls.secret + sorted_params).hexdigest() == signature